# oracle instant client and ORACLE_HOME environment variable

Tags: oracle

I have Oracle Server and Oracle Instant Client on the same machine. (Windows 7)

Notes on Instant Client state that get rid of ORACLE_HOME environment variable.

I am using SQL Developer - If I want to install packages, I do not want to hardcode the path, but do something like Oracle_Home/..... (which I don't know the proper syntax of, btw)

How would I achieve this with ORACLE_HOME environment variable gone?

What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Developer just connects to the database port. It doesn't have to know about the ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: but if I want to install a package from SQL Developer (without using GUI), do I have to hardcode the package path?

Comment: My guess is that you can still use the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to point to the directory where the tnsnames.ora resides.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle_home points to the location of where Oracle software is installed. It is needed for Oracle software to run correctly. 
It has nothing to do with the location of any package you want to install.

To install a package (I assume you are talking about an Oracle PL/SQL package) you can do this from SQLplus.

Open sqlplus and connect to the schema you want the package to reside in.

From the SQL plus command prompt type:

```
SQL>@<path to your package>\<package>
```

This will load the package into your schema.

Alternatively you can open the package in SQLDeveloper. Make a connection to the schema and compile it.

Comment: Obviously, I can load the package by hardcoding the full path - I am trying to avoid id. I just want to use relative location, because most of the packages I want do reside inside subdirectory of the oracle installation folder

Comment: Then use @? where ? is the oracle_home path.

Comment: so that means I dont get rid of the environment variable like the tutorial is suggesting, right? how do I get access to oracle_home from inside sql developer? What's the syntax? I searched but still don't know!